android: accessing soft keyboard to avoid double taps caused by shaky hands
The technical problem is to intercept keystrokes to all apps on an Android and edit them to remove double letters.
A friend with Parkinson's disease has problems with txt messages and emails because his hand shakes and he often taps a letter twice. Getting rid of the extra letter is a problem too as one tap of backspace easily becomes two. This means that he is unable to use many communication apps as it is too hard. In his case Parkinson's also affects speech so he has a considerable difficulty communicating.
One solution which occurs to me is to write a program which captures all keystrokes and removes a keystroke from the input stream if it is the same as the previous one and there is less than 500ms between them. The program has to stay resident and operate for all apps.
Is this allowed by the Android OS? Is there a class of programs which does this sort of thing to input streams?

first of all, please accept my huge compassion to your friend. Although it doesn't answer your question, didn't you try a hardware keyboard? I'm blind, and although we all use touch keyboards, I hate it and prefer hardware keyboards whenever possible.
